Installing R Studio in Anaconda
When I try to install R Studio in Anaconda, I get this error. What should I do?
├─ pin-1 is not installable because it requires
│  └─ python 3.12.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
└─ rstudio is not installable because there are no viable options
   ├─ rstudio [1.0.44|1.1.383|1.1.456] would require
   │  └─ qt 5.6.* , which requires
   │     └─ openssl 1.0.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   └─ rstudio [1.0.136|1.0.153] would require
      └─ fonts-continuum, which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel).


We have no details about your conda environment, but you seem to be using default channel where most recent RStudio version is 1.1, released in 2018. Are you sure this is what you are really after? There are more recent releases available through conda-forge , but I'd be cautious mixing it with your existing environment. Have you considered creating a new environment from scratch?


create a new conda environment:

conda create --name R


enter the new conda evironment:

conda activate R


install into this new activated enviornment R:

conda install -c conda-forge r-base r-essentials r-devtools


test which R is used now:

which R

It should show an address to your generated environment in conda.
